# How to bring back the full Xcode 4 interface?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

This is crazy! I opened two separate editor windows by double-clicking in the files navigator. Then I closed Xcode.

Now, every time I open my project Xcode is completely gone. All I get are these two separate editor windows. I tried everything to get Xcode back, but when I open this particular project there is no Xcode interface - just the two lightweight editor windows.

Did anyone else encounter this problem? Is there anything else I can do, other than creating a blank new project from scratch and copying everything over?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "lightweight editor window" in Xcode 4. What you're seeing is a window that has the toolbar, tab bar, navigator pane, and utilities pane all hidden. You can show them again from the View menu.

To bring back everything:

1. View->Show Toolbar
2. View->Show Tab Bar
3. View->Navigators->Show Navigator
4. View->Utilities->Show Utilities

The last two can also be done from buttons on the toolbar.

Depending on what you expect the window to look like, you may also need to use View->Debug Area->Show Debug Area.

Comment: Agreed - you can have multiple windows onto the same project/workspace. They're exactly, precisely the same thing. They only have different display options.

Answer (score 3):

Select one of these editor windows, and then go to View -> Show toolbar. There is the rest of your interface.

Comment: Brought back about 60% of the UI. But somehow the bottom is missing. I mean the bottom toolbar in the editor with the debug controls. I can show the console, but when I drag it down it disappears completely with no way of dragging it up again. Previously I could simply drag it up.

Comment: @openfrog: You might want to take a look at my answer, which explains the other missing 40%.

Comment: Well, yeah, but the other buttons are there on the toolbar to quickly open everything else up.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer: True, except for the tab bar. Still need to go back to the View menu for that.

Comment: in the View menu you'll see a choice called "Debug Area".  One of the items in that sub-menu is "Show Debug Area" (i.e. your missing bottom part).  Click that.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the menu and selecting Navigate and "Reveal in Project navigator"

Comment: Doesn't work. It brings back the project navigator, but only attached to that mini-editor. It's still not the full-blown Xcode UI.

Comment: @openfrog: If this answer wasn't sufficient, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

With the project open, select `View > Show Toolbar`.